# Ruby write byte to socket

Tags: ruby, sockets, byte

How can I write a byte to a socket in ruby? I specifically mean how can I write something like 0x02 to a socket. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One way of sending integer byte values would be to use [array.pack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206).

```
socket.write [0x02].pack("C")
```

Comment: @mu is too short:  Right ... it should be write.  Thanks.  I was thinking of the packing part and not the putting it on the wire part.  The puts call (I believe) adds `\n` to the end of it (resulting in two bytes).

Answer (score 4):

Something like this ?

```
require 'socket'               # Get sockets from stdlib

server = TCPServer.open(2000)  # Socket to listen on port 2000
loop {                         # Servers run forever
  client = server.accept       # Wait for a client to connect
  client.write("\x02")
  client.close                 # Disconnect from the client
}
```

Comment: `write` or `print` would be more appropriate than `puts` in this instance, if he's looking to write a byte to the socket.